# Auto Mapper Mapping Exception When Filtering

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, nullreferenceexception

C# beginner here, I want to only see the facilities where the manager has the same age as the current user.

For some reason when I publish my site with this code and try to view facilities, I get a very long error stating that:

```
***Unable to retrieve facilities from the server. Errors: "error: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types. Mapping types: WhereListIterator`1 -> IEnumerable`1 System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereListIterator`1[ ***
```

Here is the function:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IACtionResult> GetFacilities(int page, int pagesize){

var facilities = await _facilityService.GetAllfacilitiesAsync(page, pagesize);

var curr_Age = (int)HttpContext.User.GetAge();

facilities = facilities.Where(facility => facility.Manager.Age == curr_Age);

var model = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<FacilityViewModel>>(facilities);

return OK(model);
}
```

I have no issue viewing all facilities when I do not filter by age so I have no idea what could be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is caused by IEnumerable﻿ being used multiple times. [Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/PossibleMultipleEnumeration.html)

You can fix it by simply adding `.ToList()` after `.Where(...)` => `facilities = facilities.Where(...).ToList();`.

Comment: This helps! But when I try that I still get 
``` Unable to retrieve facilities from the server. Errors: "error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at XX.Portal.Controllers.FacilitiesController.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.b__0(Facility facility) in C:\Repos\XX.Portal\Controllers\FacilitiesController.cs:line 4 at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList() at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.ToListt[TSource](IEnumerable'1 source) at... ```

Comment: Probably `facility.Manager` is null. Try this change:
`facilities = facilities.Where(facility => facility.Manager != null && facility.Manager.Age == curr_Age).ToList();`

Comment: If Manager should not be null check if any of your facilities from _facilityService has Manager if not you probably have to include it with `context.Facilities.Include(x => x.Manager).ToListAsync()`

Comment: Adding the check for facility.Manager != null worked, thank you!